# Is there a way to see when the product key of a windows os was last changed?

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, product-key

Is there some way I can see when the product key of Windows Server was changed last?

I'm trying to find out if our old IT guy changed the product key on one of our MSDN licensed OSs before he left.

Comment: Why don't you just compare the current key to your records?

Comment: Well if I had records, then I probably wouldn't be asking this question.

Comment: I honestly don't know if Windows even keeps track of this, it would have no reason to, the current license is what determines if its activated or not.

Comment: Can Microsoft give you this information from their servers?